# No View Model registered for View Ish:Page:GeneralPage with DXA .NET 2.2

Tags: dxa, tridion-docs, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

I did try to prepare OOTB DXA 2.2 + Dynamic Documentation Module 2.2, had this error message and investigated and found it was config issue from my side, just to post this error message for other community users might be helpful to avoid this error.

```
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No View Model registered for View 'Ish:Page:GeneralPage'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'Ish' area registration.
at Sdl.Web.Common.Models.ModelTypeRegistry.GetViewModelType(MvcData viewData) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Common\Models\ModelTypeRegistry.cs:line 115
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildPageModel(PageModel& pageModel, PageModelData pageModelData, Boolean includePageRegions, Localization localization) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 75
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreatePageModel(PageModelData pageModelData, Boolean includePageRegions, Localization localization) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 132
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.LoadPageModel(Int32 pageId, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 362
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.b__0() in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 104
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.CreateCacheValue[T](UInt32 hash, String key, String region, Func1 addFunction, IEnumerable1 dependencies) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 133
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func1 addFunction, IEnumerable1 dependencies) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 86
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.DefaultCacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func1 addFunction, IEnumerable1 dependencies) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\DefaultCacheProvider.cs:line 63
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(Int32 pageId, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 99
at Sdl.Web.Modules.DynamicDocumentation.Controllers.ApiController.Page(Int32 publicationId, Int32 pageId) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\DynamicDocumentation\Controllers\ApiController.cs:line 72
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No View Model registered for View 'Ish:Page:GeneralPage'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'Ish' area registration.
at Sdl.Web.Common.Models.ModelTypeRegistry.GetViewModelType(MvcData viewData) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Common\Models\ModelTypeRegistry.cs:line 115
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildPageModel(PageModel& pageModel, PageModelData pageModelData, Boolean includePageRegions, Localization localization) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 75
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreatePageModel(PageModelData pageModelData, Boolean includePageRegions, Localization localization) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 132
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.LoadPageModel(Int32 pageId, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 362
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.b__0() in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 104
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.CreateCacheValue[T](UInt32 hash, String key, String region, Func1 addFunction, IEnumerable1 dependencies) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 133
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func1 addFunction, IEnumerable1 dependencies) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 86
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.DefaultCacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func1 addFunction, IEnumerable1 dependencies) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\DefaultCacheProvider.cs:line 63
at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(Int32 pageId, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 99
at Sdl.Web.Modules.DynamicDocumentation.Controllers.ApiController.Page(Int32 publicationId, Int32 pageId) in C:\Workspace\SDL-Tridion-Docs\DDWebapp\dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2\DynamicDocumentation\Controllers\ApiController.cs:line 72
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was config issue from my side I did placed the the DD Module builder pipeline in the last.

```
<add type="Sdl.Web.Modules.DynamicDocumentation.Mapping.ModelBuilder, Sdl.Web.Modules.DynamicDocumentation" />
```

[Documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-3383CE20-E108-4121-B94E-5C081A790DAE) Indeed,

Important to note:

In the modelBuilderPipeline section, add the Dynamic Documentation model builder to the pipeline, **placing it first in the list and before the Default model builder**, as the following example illustrates:

```
<modelBuilderPipeline>
   <add type="Sdl.Web.Modules.DynamicDocumentation.Mapping.ModelBuilder, Sdl.Web.Modules.DynamicDocumentation" />
   <add type="Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder, Sdl.Web.Tridion" />
   ...
   ...
 </modelBuilderPipeline>
```